# FIO: Always write error when direct=1 and use libaio in mergerfs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fuse

Linux FUSE (Filesystem in Userspace) support O_DIRECT? because I use fio benchmark to test fuse but it always shows errors when I use directIO

Mine machine is Ubuntu 4.4.0-38 x86_64 fio_version = 2.14 Below is my config file

```
[global]
ioengine=libaio
**direct=1**
time_based
runtime=60
ramp_time=30
size=64g
group_reporting

[S_100RW_1M_R]
rw=read
numjobs=1
iodepth=32
bs=1m
stonewall

[S_100RW_1M_W]
rw=write
numjobs=1
iodepth=32
bs=1m
stonewall
```

when I execute :`sudo fio fio.cfg` and it done

it shows the result of seq. read **but no results of seq. write**. it shows below:

fio: io_u error on file xxxxx : Invalid argument: write offset=0, buflen=1048576
I tried every times and the results are the same even I changed the tested device.

how come it happened?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

That suggests that for whatever reason the filesystem "liked" the `O_DIRECT` on the initial open but went on to refuse to do something when it came to time to do the 1 megabyte `O_DIRECT` write. I would guess you will get a similar result using `dd` with `oflag=direct bs=1M` etc.

Comment: @yayaya Did the dd suffer the same fate?

Comment: yap, seems it's the problem of mergerfs.